# Column names are not recognized? How to set the column names?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset for which I am not able to call the columns. In the screen shoot below, I have marked in yellow what I need to be recognized as column (Vale On, Petroleo etc.) and the Date column, which I need to recognize as date since I am working with time series data.

I have tried to reset index and some solutions related but nothing worked. I am new to Python, so I am sorry if it is too obvious.

[image: Screenshot Dataframe]

Comment: Your column names are 0, 1, 2... The header is incorrectly set as the first row of your data.

Comment: Looks like your dataframe's 1st row contains column labels. Try `df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]`

Comment: How did you create the dataframe? `pd.read_csv()` will normally use the first line of the file as the column names.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have imported the data on Excel format, but before getting to this point, I have done some modifications on the imported dataset ( like transposing, for example). I have used the code " df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]" for setting the column names and it worked. Now I only need to change the column "Date" to "Datetime" type, which is not working. I am trying " df1 = df1[pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])] " but it returns " ParserError: Unknown string format: Date" . Any ideas?

Comment: I have solved the problem like this: first I have imported my main dataframe once again and after deleting some rows, I applied the command " df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ". After transposing the dataframe and transposing back, I realized that the df was again in another format, so I used the same command above to get datetype once more. Everything works fine. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# use first row as column names
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

# and then drop it
df = df.iloc[1:]

# convert first col to date
# if it doesnt work, try passing format=... refer https://strftime.org/
# also https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

A debugging hint if parsing the date keeps failing is to check if your date strings are consistent, perhaps like so: `df['Date'].str.len().value_counts()`. That should hopefully return only one length. If that returns multiple rows,  that means you have inconsistent and anomalous data which you'll have to clean.

Comment: I was not able to convert the first col to Date:  ParserError: Unknown string format: Date. 
My date looks like "1980-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" . I do not know how this "Z" appeared. 
Initially I had a dataframe in which the date was in "date time" type, but I needed to transpose the dataframe and automatically all my columns became "object type". I think the error can be related to that somehow.

Comment: There might be a problematic date in one of the rows, are you sure the data is perfect?

Comment: One way to check problematic dates could be try verifying if you get only one length for `df['Date'].str.len().value_counts()` before you parse it -- that'll tell you if all Date strings are consistent or if there's a particular row that's messing it up with erroneous / anomalous data

Comment: I am not sure if the Date is all right because it is a really huge dataset. Executing the codes above I got " 4.0    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64"

Comment: `4.0 1` means you probably checked only the first row? What's your date formatted as?

Comment: Your Date column must be parseable as a datetime object. Can you find a format from https://strftime.org/ that fits your Date string?

Comment: I attempted to check the whole column. The dtype of the column "date" is "object. My date is in the format ""1980-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", so I think it is  %Y %m %d %H %M %S %f according t the strftime  you sent me.

Comment: I have solved the problem like this: first I have imported my main dataframe once again and after deleting some rows, I applied the command " df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ". 
After transposing the dataframe and transposing back, I realized that the df was again in another format, so I used the same command above to get datetype once more. Everything works fine. Thanks guys